# DynamoDB user segmentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-dynamodb

Is there an industry standard way to segment data by company / user / client in DynamoDB? If I was using a relational database, I think i'd have a different database for the level I'm thinking of here. Rather than having keys to mark rows as belonging to a given entity, I'd like to have a chunk of data which I can programmatically contain my App to per-user, without the sort of error that having the wrong key or a logic error in code my expose data. Also so I can just blow away all the data at a go when we're done with it (no longer a client, or for testing). I guess I could use table name prefixes, but I think there's likely a limit on the number of tables, and this isn't as clean as would be idea. Would I need to set up separate accounts for each, even if there's all being billed to us?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. You need to design the schema to meet the needs of your application / work.